# Implementing StringBuilder delete method using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stringbuilder

I am trying to complete a project that requires me to use no loops of any kind, instead using only recursion.  I have to create a StringBuilder class using LinkedLists instead of arrays.  I would appreciate if somebody could help me implement recursion in this method delete().

```
public MyStringBuilder delete(int start, int end)
    {
        if(!(start < 0 || start > length || end <= start)){
            CNode currNode = firstC;
            CNode startNode = currNode;
            if(start == 0){
                for(int i = 1; i < end +1; i++){
                    currNode = currNode.next;
                    length -= 1;
                }
                firstC = currNode;
            }else if (end > length){
                for(int i = 1; i < start; i++){
                    currNode = currNode.next;
                }
                length = start;
                currNode.next = null;
                lastC = currNode;
            } else {
                for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
                    //find starting deletion point
                    if(i == (start - 1)){
                        startNode = currNode;
                    }
                    currNode = currNode.next;
                }
                length = length - (end-start);
                //actual deletion part
                startNode.next = currNode;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to understand, even though you said there shouldn't be any loops, you still have some loops mentioned there.

I have tried to come up with a solution to the problem using linked lists. I had to include for loops here and there. So, have a look...

> `ListNode.java`

```
public class ListNode<T>{
    public T data;
    public ListNode<T> next;
    public int nos;
}
```

> `MyStringBuilder.java`

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyStringBuilder {
    ListNode<Character> list = new ListNode<Character>();

    public void add(String s){
        ListNode<Character> p1 = list; 
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            p1.data = s.charAt(i);
            p1.next = new ListNode<Character>();
            p1 = p1.next;
        }
        list.nos=s.length();

    }

    public void print(){
        ListNode<Character> p1 = list;

        while(p1.next!=null){
            System.out.print(p1.data);
            p1= p1.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void delete(int start, int end){
        ListNode<Character> p1 = list;
        ListNode<Character> p2;
        ListNode<Character> prev =list;
        if (start < 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("first argument cannot be less than 0");
        }
        if (start > end){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("first argument cannot be greater than second");
        }
        if (end > list.nos){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("second argument cannot be greater than size of string");
        }

        if(start==0){
            while(end!=0){
                p1=p1.next;
                end--;
            }
            list = p1.next;
            return;
        }

        //iterate over start steps
        int i=start;
        while(i!=0){
            prev = p1;
            p1= p1.next;
            i--;
        }

        p2 = p1.next;

        end = end-start;
        while(end!=0){
            p2 = p2.next;
            end--;
        }
        prev.next = p2;
    }
}
```

I hope the solution works for you. I tried the following sample to check if it worked. I wrote these codes in `main()`

```
        MyStringBuilder abc = new MyStringBuilder();
        abc.add("apocalypto");

        abc.delete(2, 6);
        abc.print();
```

I got this answer: **appto**

Answer (score 0):

To implement this using recursion, you have to do two things: define a base case, and figure out how to go from one recursive call to another. I won't write out the code, but here's a general idea of what to do:

First, let's think about what the delete method does. It deletes from **a** inclusive to **b** exclusive. Thus, a good base case is that we reach our **b** and we stop deleting.

Now, to go from one step to another, we can simply delete the node we are at and recursively call our function for the next nodes.

However, be careful when you implement the logic; the best way to handle this is to keep track of *how many nodes* you want to delete and use that as your base case. The reason for this is that deletion modifies the list as you go through it and you need to keep track of how many nodes to delete till you hit **b**.

If you just keep this general guidelines in mind, the code should somewhat write itself. Feel free to ask any questions!